# Comparing a host of csv files - in particular two CSV files per call

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, variables, comparison

I have already built on a Powershell script that I've found and expanded it to include multiple comparisons of two CSV files.

I'm new to PowerShell and I know that you can do an If statement, but I don't know how to work it yet so I've had to build the PS script out line-by-line,so any help would be greatly appreciated;

```
# Set default vCenters
$VCServer1 = "Server1"
$VCServer2 = "Server2"
$VCServer3 = "Server3"
$VCServer4 = "Server4"

# Set the default export file path
$XlsxDir1 = "E:\$VCServer1\"
$XlsxDir2 = "E:\$VCServer2\"
$XlsxDir3 = "E:\$VCServer3\"
$XlsxDir4 = "E:\$VCServer4\"

# Set the default vSwitch file path
$vSwitchDir1 = "E:\$VCServer1\vSwitch"
$vSwitchDir2 = "E:\$VCServer2\vSwitch"
$vSwitchDir3 = "E:\$VCServer3\vSwitch"
$vSwitchDir4 = "E:\$VCServer4\vSwitch"

# Set the default dvSwitch file path
$dvSwitchDir1 = "E:\$VCServer1\dvSwitch"
$dvSwitchDir2 = "E:\$VCServer2\dvSwitch"
$dvSwitchDir3 = "E:\$VCServer3\dvSwitch"
$dvSwitchDir4 = "E:\$VCServer4\dvSwitch"

# Set the default vSwitch file
$vSwitch1Path = Get-Item -Path $vSwitchDir1\vSwitch_*.csv
$vSwitch2Path = Get-Item -Path $vSwitchDir2\vSwitch_*.csv
$vSwitch3Path = Get-Item -Path $vSwitchDir3\vSwitch_*.csv
$vSwitch4Path = Get-Item -Path $vSwitchDir4\vSwitch_*.csv

# Set the default dvSwitch file
$dvSwitch1Path = Get-Item -Path $dvSwitchDir1\dvSwitch_*.csv
$dvSwitch2Path = Get-Item -Path $dvSwitchDir2\dvSwitch_*.csv
$dvSwitch3Path = Get-Item -Path $dvSwitchDir3\dvSwitch_*.csv
$dvSwitch4Path = Get-Item -Path $dvSwitchDir4\dvSwitch_*.csv

# find the latest vSwitch file
$vSwitch1Lat = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $vSwitchDir1 -Filter 'vSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)
$vSwitch2Lat = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $vSwitchDir2 -Filter 'vSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)
$vSwitch3Lat = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $vSwitchDir3 -Filter 'vSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)
$vSwitch4Lat = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $vSwitchDir4 -Filter 'vSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)

# find the latest dvSwitch file
$dvSwitch1Lat = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dvSwitchDir1 -Filter 'dvSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)
$dvSwitch2Lat = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dvSwitchDir2 -Filter 'dvSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)
$dvSwitch3Lat = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dvSwitchDir3 -Filter 'dvSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)
$dvSwitch4Lat = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dvSwitchDir4 -Filter 'dvSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)

# find the older vSwitch file
$vSwitch1Old = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $vSwitchDir1 -Filter 'vSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1)
$vSwitch2Old = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $vSwitchDir2 -Filter 'vSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1)
$vSwitch3Old = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $vSwitchDir3 -Filter 'vSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1)
$vSwitch4Old = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $vSwitchDir4 -Filter 'vSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1)

# find the older dvSwitch file
$dvSwitch1Old = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dvSwitchDir1 -Filter 'dvSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1)
$dvSwitch2Old = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dvSwitchDir2 -Filter 'dvSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1)
$dvSwitch3Old = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dvSwitchDir3 -Filter 'dvSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1)
$dvSwitch4Old = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dvSwitchDir4 -Filter 'dvSwitch_*.csv' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1)

# define output destinations
$outFilePaths = @{
  vSwitch1 = "$vSwitchDir1\Changes.csv"
  vSwitch2 = "$vSwitchDir2\Changes.csv"
  vSwitch3 = "$vSwitchDir3\Changes.csv"
  vSwitch4 = "$vSwitchDir4\Changes.csv"
  dvSwitch1 = "$dvSwitchDir1\Changes.csv"
  dvSwitch2 = "$dvSwitchDir2\Changes.csv"
  dvSwitch3 = "$dvSwitchDir3\Changes.csv"
  dvSwitch4 = "$dvSwitchDir4\Changes.csv"
  # Latest = 'E:\TEMP\LatestChanges.csv'
}

# find all the subsequent versions of the file, make sure 
# they're sorted by name, then store them in an array
$FileCount = $dvSwitch1Old

# make sure we've located at least one subsequent version - otherwise there's nothing to compare against!
if ($FileCount.Count -gt 0) {
    # let's start by comparing original with the latest version
    # 
    # $files[-1] is going to evaluate to the _last_ item in the $files array
    $vSwitch1LatChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($vSwitch1Lat |Get-Content) -DifferenceObject ($vSwitch1Old |Get-Content)
    $vSwitch2LatChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($vSwitch2Lat |Get-Content) -DifferenceObject ($vSwitch2Old |Get-Content)
    $vSwitch3LatChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($vSwitch3Lat |Get-Content) -DifferenceObject ($vSwitch3Old |Get-Content)
    $vSwitch4LatChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($vSwitch4Lat |Get-Content) -DifferenceObject ($vSwitch4Old |Get-Content)

    $dvSwitch1LatChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($dvSwitch1Lat |Get-Content) -DifferenceObject ($dvSwitch1Old |Get-Content)
    $dvSwitch2LatChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($dvSwitch2Lat |Get-Content) -DifferenceObject ($dvSwitch2Old |Get-Content)
    $dvSwitch3LatChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($dvSwitch3Lat |Get-Content) -DifferenceObject ($dvSwitch3Old |Get-Content)
    $dvSwitch4LatChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($dvSwitch4Lat |Get-Content) -DifferenceObject ($dvSwitch4Old |Get-Content)

    # output to a file
    $vSwitch1LatChanges |Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize |Out-File $outFilePaths['vSwitch1'] -Width 200
    $vSwitch2LatChanges |Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize |Out-File $outFilePaths['vSwitch2'] -Width 200
    $vSwitch3LatChanges |Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize |Out-File $outFilePaths['vSwitch3'] -Width 200
    $vSwitch4LatChanges |Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize |Out-File $outFilePaths['vSwitch4'] -Width 200

    $dvSwitch1LatChanges |Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize |Out-File $outFilePaths['dvSwitch1'] -Width 200
    $dvSwitch2LatChanges |Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize |Out-File $outFilePaths['dvSwitch2'] -Width 200
    $dvSwitch3LatChanges |Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize |Out-File $outFilePaths['dvSwitch3'] -Width 200
    $dvSwitch4LatChanges |Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize |Out-File $outFilePaths['dvSwitch4'] -Width 200
}
else {
    Write-Host "Updated files are missing" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red
}
```

I'm not really sure about validation check $FileCount = $dvSwitch1Old, but I know that this one did work so I knew that the script would continue, but ideally I'd like it to check each the Older csv files for both vSwitch and dvSwitch.

Another thing is that once the comparison file has been produced, it doesn't include any headers, so ideally I'd like these within the Changes.csv file if possible.

Cheers in advance

The code does work, however I believe it could do with a bit more work from an experienced PS scripter and also when it trys to do validation/pre-checks before it starts the next code.